HydratedCubit for checking user onboarding state
I am pretty new to mobile development. I've been working with Cubit and HydratedCubit to do some of the state management in my App. Based on some the reading I've been doing HydratedCubit can be used to store shared settings so they get restored in the next session. I've been trying to figure out how do this cleanly for Onboarding state of the application and I'm a little confused. The application flow should go as follows:
If the user has never finished onboarding:
SplachPage() -> Onboarding() -> Login()
If the user has onboarded.
SplashPage() -> Login()
The SplashPage should always display the logo for 2 seconds.
I'm trying to figure where my BlocProvider and BlocBuilder for the HydratedCutib should go. I could put it in the Onboarding page and navigate to the Login immediately if the state shows that the user has onboarded in the past. The problem with this is that it would always make my app go to the onboarding page when loading and that feels a bit unnecessary. On the other hand, I could put the provider and builder in the Splash page and not navigate to Onboarding if the user has Onboarded already but I don't want the user to wait 2 seconds in the SplashPage again when the state changes and I'm not sure how I would go about differencing if we are loading SplashPage for the first time or rebuilding it so this may lead to the user having to wait another 2 seconds in the SplashPage after onboarding.
Is there something I'm not understanding or maybe HydratedCubit is not a good fit for this use case?
Thanks

First, one thing must be clarified before moving on with my answer. Do you want your app to "remember" that the user has completed in the past the onboarding procedure, even if the user uninstalls/installs the app?
if yes, hydration is not a solution here because as soon as the user uninstalls the app, the hydrated data are deleted as well.
Assuming that the above is not the problem, what I would do is make a wrapper widget for the login page. Let's call this OnBoardingWrapper, which will accept a Widget parameter child. In our case, the child is the LoginPage.
This wrapper will have a simple logic in the builder if the onBoarding is already been done in the past, then render the LoginPage Widget, else render the OnBoarding widget.
On this Wrapper widget, a hydrated cubit can be provided which only has a state value like isOnBoardingCompleted and a method that sets this value from false to true.
So if the onBoarding is rendered, on the completion the method is called setting the value to true and displaying the login page.
if the user re-visit the app after the completion of onboarding flow, the hydrated state with the isOnBoardingCompleted == true will be retrieved and the user will skip the onboarding.
